# Is there a way to link from one part of document to another part of the same document using python-docx?

Tags: python, ms-word, hyperlink, python-docx

My objective is to list out the various contents of a document in a tabular format and then link the text to the locations they are referring to.
It is similar to the navigation pane of MS Word in which the various headings can be seen and can jump from one location to another using the links.

Is there any way in which I can link one part of the document to another such that when you click the link you jump to the location?

I am trying to code in this format.

```
head = document.add_heading('aaa', level=1)
add_to_table(document, head)
```

Pass this heading to another function which would add to the heading to a table.

```
def add_to_table(document, heading):
    table = document.tables[0]
    cells = table.add_row().cells
    cells[0].text = heading.text
    add_hyperlink(cells[0], heading)
```

I am not sure if there is any function like `add_hyperlink` as I have written above. Is there any way this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using Microsoft fields, or [hyperlink field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-hyperlink-field-864f8577-eb2a-4e55-8c90-40631748ef53?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to be more precise:

> Syntax: `{ HYPERLINK "Filename" [Switches ] }`

> Switches
> `\l`
> Specifies a location in the file, such as a bookmark, where this hyperlink will jump.
> ...

Like in HTML where you have element id and inner links referring to the element as `#id`, here instead of ids, we use bookmarks.

Since python-docx still doesn't have support for adding custom fields, I've made my own for our fork here: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/commit/a7f9f874886c8e2166489ee3cf07311c483989ac

So let's say that we have a document which has `bookmark_num_1` bookmark somewhere inserted in the document, then adding a paragraph, in this case, would look something like:

```
    doc = docx.Document()
    bkm_name = "bookmark_num_1"
    p = doc.add_paragraph()
    r = p.add_run()
    r.add_fldChar('begin')
    r.add_instrText(rf'HYPERLINK \l "{bkm_name}"')
    r.add_fldChar('separate')
    r = p.add_run('hyperlink text towards bookmark_num_1. ctrl+click to go there.')
    r.add_fldChar('end')
```

My next guess is that you want to add bookmarks dynamically, there are two open PRs for that you might find useful:
https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/pull/539, https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/pull/445

Note there's also some work in this direction you might find to be useful https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/pull/278